# Cube and dot product

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let $ABCDA_1B_1C_1D_1$ is a cube оf edge length $a$. I am trying the find the dot product $\vec{D_1B}\cdot\vec{AC}$. It is known that $D_1B=a\sqrt3$ and $AC=a\sqrt{2}$, so the only thing left is to find the angle between $D_1B$ and $AC$ as $$\vec{D_1B}\cdot\vec{AC}=\left|\vec{D_1B}\right|.\left|\vec{AC}\right|.\cos\measuredangle\left(\vec{D_1B},\vec{AC}\right)$$ How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly find the vectors $\vec{D_1B}$ and $\vec{AC}$ by putting the cube in a $3$d coordinate system.

Let $A=(0,0,0)$, $B=(1,0,0)$, $A_1=(0,0,1)$, $C=(1,1,0)$ etcetera. Then
$$\vec{D_1B}=\vec{B}-\vec{D_1}=(1,-1,-1)$$
and $$\vec{AC}=\vec{C}-\vec{A}=(1,1,0)$$
Now find their scalar product.